# How to show correct answer even if i click the wrong answer uibutton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm trying to make a quiz app in iOS. Now I'm facing how to show the correct answer even if I click the wrong answer. In this app, in quiz screen contains question with several possible answers (Four answer options), here i display the question and no of questions count in uilabel and four answer options set in uibuttons title label. And I set the tag value of each and every buttons. In button action (here I set common button action method for all of the four buttons) I set the background image for correct answers and wrong answers based the compare the button title label string with correct answer array value. But I can't able to fix   how to display the correct answer even i click the wrong answers.

if anybody know the solution please kindly guide me and I will really appreciate to you.

```
    - (void)loadDictionary
{
    quizzDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"France, Allemagne, Royaume-Uni",@"1/5",@"Quels sont les trois pays formant la Triple Entente ?",@"France, Royaume-Uni, Russie",@"France, Allemagne, Royaume-Uni",@"France, Italie, Royaume-Uni",@"France, Italie, Royaume-Uni", nil],@"1",[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"les Carpates",@"2/5",@"Lequel de ces chaînes de montagnes n'est pas français?",@"les Alpes",@"les Vosges",@"les Carpates",@"les Pyrénées", nil],@"2",[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"la mer Baltique",@"3/5",@"Lequel de ces plans d'eau ne borde pas la France?",@"la mer Baltique",@"la Méditerrannée",@"La Manche",@"l'Atlantique", nil],@"3",[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bordeaux, Marseille, Lille",@"4/5",@"Les trois plus grandes villes françaises sont",@"Paris, Lyon, Marseille",@"Paris, Lille, Marseille",@"Paris, Marseille, Bordeaux",@"Bordeaux, Marseille, Lille", nil],@"4",[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"is gaining",@"5/5",@"Le territoire de la forêt française",@"is gaining",@"is shrinking",@"is staying the same",@"is unknown", nil],@"5", nil];
    NSLog(@"the dic value = %@",quizzDict);
}

#pragma mark - Scroll - Slider

- (void)loadScrollViewContents
{
    [questionslbl removeFromSuperview];
    pageOfScroll            = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<[quizzDict allKeys].count;i++)
    {
        questionslbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*240, 0, 240, questionScrollView.frame.size.height)];
        [questionslbl setTag:i];
        [questionslbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [questionScrollView addSubview:questionslbl];
        [questionScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        NSArray *quesArr = [quizzDict valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(i+1)]];
        NSString *string = [quesArr objectAtIndex:2];
        UILabel *templbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 , 0, 240, 42)];
        [templbl setNumberOfLines:2];
        [templbl setText:NSLocalizedString(string, @"")];
        [templbl setTextColor:LIGHT_YELLOW_COLOR];
        [templbl setFont:MRSEAVES_BOLD(17)];
        [questionslbl addSubview:templbl];
    }
     [questionScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((questionScrollView.frame.size.width*[quizzDict allKeys].count), questionScrollView.frame.size.height)];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    pageOfScroll          = scrollView.contentOffset.x/scrollView.frame.size.width;

    NSArray *quesArr      = [quizzDict valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(pageOfScroll+1)]];
    NSString *countstr    = [quesArr objectAtIndex:1];
    [questionCountlbl              setText:NSLocalizedString(countstr, @"")];
    [questionCountlbl              setFont:MRSEAVES_BOLD(22)];

    NSString *ans1        = [quesArr objectAtIndex:3];
    [answerBtnOne                  setTitle:NSLocalizedString(ans1, @"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [answerBtnOne.titleLabel       setFont:MRSEAVES_BOLD(15)];

    NSString *ans2        = [quesArr objectAtIndex:4];
    [answerBtnTwo                  setTitle:NSLocalizedString(ans2, @"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [answerBtnTwo.titleLabel       setFont:MRSEAVES_BOLD(15)];

    NSString *ans3        = [quesArr objectAtIndex:5];
    [answerBtnThree                  setTitle:NSLocalizedString(ans3, @"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [answerBtnThree.titleLabel       setFont:MRSEAVES_BOLD(15)];

    NSString *ans4        = [quesArr objectAtIndex:6];
    [answerBtnFour                  setTitle:NSLocalizedString(ans4, @"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [answerBtnFour.titleLabel       setFont:MRSEAVES_BOLD(15)];
}

- (IBAction)AnswerBtnAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Tag value = %ld",(long)[sender tag]);
    NSArray  *quesArr      = [quizzDict valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(pageOfScroll+1)]];
    NSString *countstr     = [quesArr objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *optionsArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:answerBtnOne.titleLabel.text,answerBtnTwo.titleLabel.text,answerBtnThree.titleLabel.text,answerBtnFour.titleLabel.text, nil];
    NSLog(@"optionsArr = %@",optionsArr);

    int answeredOption = [optionsArr containsObject:countstr];
    answeredOption ++ ;

    if([sender tag] == 1001)
    {
        if([answerBtnOne.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:countstr])
        {
            [answerBtnOne   setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"quiz_list_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [answerBtnTwo   setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
            [answerBtnThree setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
            [answerBtnFour  setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{nextBtn.alpha = 1.0;}];
        }
        else
        {
            [answerBtnOne setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"quiz_list_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
    else if([sender tag] == 1002)
    {
        if([answerBtnTwo.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:countstr])
        {
            [answerBtnTwo   setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"quiz_list_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [answerBtnOne   setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
            [answerBtnThree setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
            [answerBtnFour  setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{nextBtn.alpha = 1.0;}];
        }
        else
        {
            [answerBtnTwo setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"quiz_list_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
    else if([sender tag] == 1003)
    {
        if([answerBtnThree.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:countstr])
        {
            [answerBtnThree setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"quiz_list_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [answerBtnOne   setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
            [answerBtnTwo   setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
            [answerBtnFour  setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{nextBtn.alpha = 1.0;}];
        }
        else
        {
            [answerBtnThree setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"quiz_list_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
    else if([sender tag] == 1004)
    {
        if([answerBtnFour.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:countstr])
        {
            [answerBtnFour   setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"quiz_list_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [answerBtnOne    setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
            [answerBtnTwo    setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
            [answerBtnThree  setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{nextBtn.alpha = 1.0;}];
        }
        else
        {
            [answerBtnFour setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"quiz_list_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

Here above the loadDictionary and loadScrollViewContents method was called in vieDidLoad.

The loadScrollView method was used to display the questions with slides from right to left.

I used to display the no of questions count and four answer options in scroll delegate method.

And final AnswerBtnAction is a common action method for all of the four answer buttons.

Kindly give the suggestion for how to show the correct answer even I click the wrong answer button.

Answer (score -1):

Fist of all, your code is really hard to read.

Second, you should change your `quizzDict` first, it makes your code becomes messy. Something like this

```
aQuestion = @{@“questionNumber” : NSInteger,
        @“question” : NSString,
        @“answers” : NSArray of answers,
        @“correctAnswer” : NSInteger};

quizzArray = NSArray of aQuestion;
```

then you can access to each value in `aQuestion` by using

`quizzArray[i][@"questionNumber"]`

That should make things easier now.

You could set `UIButton.tag = 1 or 2 or 3 or 4` then when user select an option:

```
-(void)selectAnAnswer:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (sender.tag == [quizzArray[i][@“correctAnswer”] integerValue]) //i is number of question
    {
        //go to next question
    } else {
        //show correct answer
    }
}
```